# Delete lines with specific word in file

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I want to make an output file which excludes the lines who has numbers in another file that are present in the column 3 of the input file.

To include the lines with the numbers in column 3 I used this script (with help from Guru):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}($3 in a)' extract.file input.file > output file
```

But now I do not want to copy the lines with the numbers to the output file.

As an example:
I have extract.file with:

```
123
689
456
```

And input.file with

```
1 AB 123 home 123
1 AC 568 cat 123
1 BC 689 dog 565
1 BB 456 car 456
```

And I want an outcome file with only:

```
1 AC 568 cat 123
```

Does anyone know how to change the script or has another script that will work on this?

Answer (score 1):

Negate the condition:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}!($3 in a)' extract.file input.file
```

Answer (score 0):

The ( x in array ) returns a value, so to do "not in array", you can to do this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}($3 in a ==0)' extract.file input.file
```

this also work.

Comment: `==0` is a misleading notion of the clearer `!`

Comment: @heemayl i know it is a little misleading but it's work and solution i should mention